# SAS unable to interpret symbol "≤" in macro execution?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Can you please explain why SAS interprets "≤" as "=" after execution in a macro or in `proc report`?

For example

```
%let a= ≤ ;

%put a is equal to &a;
```

The SAS log shows the following message:

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable A resolves to =
a is equal to =
```

I also used quoting/masking functions, but it didn't help.

Comment: after execution it interpret "≤" as "=" .

Comment: SAS doesn't have UTF-8 support enabled by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

≤ is not part of the standard ASCII character set.

It may be the case that the SAS Editor doesn't support extended character sets, e.g. UTF-8 or Unicode.

When I copy/paste the ≤ symbol from my browser into SAS Editor, it becomes the = character.

If you wish to do a less-than-or-equals logical comparision in datastep or macro, simply use `<=`.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I just wonder how to display it in on report define statement.

Comment: If you want to embed the symbol in your output, e.g. in a title or column heading, and you're sending it to ODS HTML, simply use `define var / '&le;' ;`.

Comment: I need to add into my rtf using ODS statement.